# Can chain homotopies be viewed as natural transformations?

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory

From what I can understand, apart from the usual chain complex category of chain complexes and chain maps, we can also view chain complexes as functors $F,G: (\mathbb{N}, \leq)^{\text{op}}\to \mathbf{Ab}$ with $F(i+1 \to i)F(i+2 \to i+1) = 0\ \forall i\in \mathbb{N}$ and chain maps as natural transformations $\alpha: F\Rightarrow G$, where $(\mathbb{N}, \leq)$ is regarded as a poset category.

My question is that can we also characterize chain homotopies between two chain maps as natural transformations, perhaps in an $\mathbf{Ab}$-enriched 2-category (if that even is a thing)?

Comment: You are asking for a morphism between natural transformations – sometimes called a modification – but to have such things we would need not merely a 2-category but a 3-category. So the short answer to your question as written is no. It may be possible to concoct a special 3-category for the purpose but it would be artificial.